# Custom pagination on MVC application

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC application which shows records on HTML table with pagination. For pagination, I have used **PagedList**. I want to display "next" and "previous" button , which needs to be displayed next 10 pages instead of showing next page on the pagination.

Please find my code below

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {   int pagesize = 10;
        int pageindex = 1;
        pageindex = page.HasValue ? (Convert.ToInt32(page)) : 1;
        var listdata = getdata();            
        return View(listdata.ToPagedList(pageindex,pagesize));
    }
```

Please find the pagination added on the view

```
<div id="container" style="margin-left: 20px">
    <div class="pagination" style="margin-left: 400px">
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to skip current 10 pages and need to show next 10 pages on the pagination, when I click "next" button on the pagination. Can any one help me to do this?

Comment: As I remember PagedList has a lot of versions and forks. Better tell us which package you used.

Comment: But I guess you will have to adapt the source for this.